# Show all instances of a string on three columns by using a helper column

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am using the below code to show all instances of a string found on specific three columns.
it has a side effect that using later `autofiletr` on any column then all the hidden rows are shown again.
I seek for a helper column answer to overcome that issue.
In advance, thanks for any help.

```
Sub Show_all_instances_on_three_columns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lcol_n As Long, lastcol As String
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, crit_Filter_Three_Columns As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
     lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                     'Last_Row on Column "A"
      lcol_n = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column           'Last_Column number on Row 2
        lastcol = Split(Cells(1, lcol_n).Address(True, False), "$")(0)        'Letter of Last_Column

    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:" & lastcol & LRow)                                'Source Range to apply Filter on it

    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter                              'Set AutoFilter if not already set
    
    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
       
    crit_Filter_Three_Columns = "*test*"
      
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=crit_Filter_Three_Columns, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If rng.Cells(i, 3).Value Like crit_Filter_Three_Columns Then rng.Rows(i).Hidden = False    'Unhide according to the column_3
        If rng.Cells(i, 7).Value Like crit_Filter_Three_Columns Then rng.Rows(i).Hidden = False    'Unhide according to the column_7
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure I correctly understood your question. So you want having visible all rows containing in columns C, F and G columns strings containing 'crit_Filter_Three_Columns'. **Containing** because of `Like` using... Would be such an understanding a correct tone? And, like a method, to create a helper column and finally filter by it.  Is this what you need? Or checking for an exact match of 'crit_Filter_Three_Columns'?

Comment: One issue not so clear: do you need "an **exact match** of 'crit_Filter_Three_Columns'" or `an exact match of 'crit_Filter_Three_Columns' **should be contained** in the three columns strings?

Comment: @FaneDuru , no exact match of `crit_Filter_Three_Columns` , e.g `"*test*"`

Comment: OK, I missed the wildcards... In fact, I can see that you modified it after I comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub Show_all_instances_on_three_columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lcol_n As Long, lastcol As String
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, crit_Filter_Three_Columns As String
    
    Dim arr, arrH, hlpCol As Long, rngHelp As Range
    Const helpCol As String = "HelpCol"
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
     lRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row                     'Last_Row on Column "A"
      lcol_n = ws.cells(2, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column          'Last_Column number on Row 2
        lastcol = Split(cells(1, lcol_n).address(True, False), "$")(0)     'Letter of Last_Column
                                                                           'helper column number (first empty one)
        
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:" & lastcol & lRow)                             'Source Range to apply Filter on it
    
    
    crit_Filter_Three_Columns = "*test*"
    
    'determine the helper column and extend (or not the headers range):
    Set rngHelp = ws.rows(2).Find(what:=helpCol, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngHelp Is Nothing Then
        hlpCol = rngHelp.column
    Else
        hlpCol = lcol_n + 1
        ws.cells(2, hlpCol).Value = helpCol
        Set rng = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.count + 1)
    End If
    
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter 'autofilter the resized range
    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    arr = rng.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
    ReDim arrH(1 To UBound(arr) - 1, 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep the helper character ("H")
   
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 3) Like crit_Filter_Three_Columns Or _
                 arr(i, 6) Like crit_Filter_Three_Columns Or _
                 arr(i, 7) Like crit_Filter_Three_Columns Then
            arrH(i - 1, 1) = "H"
        End If
    Next i
    
    'drop the helper array (arrH) content in the appropriate column:
    ws.cells(2, hlpCol).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrH), 1).Value2 = arrH

    
    'Filter the range  by helper column, for "H":
     rng.AutoFilter field:=hlpCol, Criteria1:="H", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Tested now.

Please, also test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Waleed Me neither, but I do not care too much. Not testing/checking the code at all, there may be typos, or other kind of mistakes. I only wanted to deliver a piece of code to be at least a hint for you. I did not know that you will also leave the office... I will test it now, correct and update it in some minutes...

Comment: @Waleed In the previous not tested code, I found a typo, a double (`i`) declaration and I changed a little the logic of the code in terms of resizing the headers range for filtering, if the helper column exists or not...

Comment: Now it works perfectly. I got some time to understand this part (using -1)  `ReDim arrH(1 To UBound(arr) - 1, 1 To 1)`  , and I later changed to `ReDim arrH(2 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)` and `arrH(i, 1) = "H"` and it also works and more easier for me to understand.

Comment: also please, Is there a differnce between using `LookIn:=xlValues` and `LookIn:=xlFormulas` ? I remembered that you earlier said you always used xlFormulas

Comment: @Waleed That `-1` was chosen because the array content started to be loaded from the second row and **the array content is dropped starting from the third one**... When I said that "always used `xlFormulas`" I was **strictly** referring of the case of using `Find` to **determine the last column, even if it is hidden**... Otherwise, `xlValues` is exactly what `AutoFilter` needs for correctly returning what you want.

Comment: my last (deleted) comment was here and not on the other question. I found the answer very easy ,So I thought you refused to reply (sorry). Anyhow, I could add wildcards to strings by using `Split` and later `Join` and then append `"*"` at beginning and last of textbox.value

Comment: @Waleed I do not remember exactly your comment meaning, but I think no need to firstly split and secondly "append". You should simple replace spaces with wildcards (using `Replace`) and also add them to the string endings... In one code line, I think. But talking about "textbox.value" I am thinking about the other question... And the problem is that the array bilt in this way will not be accepted by `Autofilter`, which accepts only two such strings containing wildcards.

Comment: @Waleed But it is a way to make in appropriate array, able to work for `AutoFilter`, even there. In a different way...